# kie drools wb distribution 6.2 with c# app getting error to communicate with rules

Tags: c#, visual-studio, drools, rule-engine

kie drools wb distribution 6.2 is used to compile rules and execute in visual studio 2015, when i call a c# based function in rule, its show errors. 
using kie drools vs 2015 c# code, rule engine drl file codes and errors  are showing below:

c# code

```html
    namespace com.IKVM_Drools_App
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Program
    {
        
        public static void debugResult(String str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nRULE FIRED: " + str);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            CustomerRecord workingObj = new CustomerRecord();
            workingObj.Id = "111-111";
            workingObj.Status = "NORMAL";
            workingObj.Value = 5;
            workingObj.DaysSinceLastOrder = 95;


            // Load the knowledge base:
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

            Resource rs = ks.getResources().newFileSystemResource(@"C:\Users\Binu\Music\KIE_Rule1.drl");
            KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

            kfs.write("src/main/resources/simple.drl", rs);
            Console.WriteLine("\nStream Set ");
            Console.WriteLine("\nReading DRL (Please wait... this may take a few moments...) ");

            KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
            Console.WriteLine("... Finished ");
            Results results = kb.getResults();
            if (results.hasMessages(org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR))
                Console.WriteLine(results.getMessages(Message.Level.ERROR));



            KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
            KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();

           

            kSession.insert(workingObj);
            kSession.fireAllRules();
            Console.ReadLine();
}}}
```

class

```html
namespace com.IKVM_Drools_App
{
    public class CustomerRecord
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Status { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int DaysSinceLastOrder { get; set; }
        public int TotalOrders { get; set; }

        public CustomerRecord()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

rule.drl

```html
package com.IKVM_Drools_App
rule "LargeOrder"
    when
      custOrder : CustomerRecord( Value > 50 )
    then
         System.out.println("Large Order");
end
```

This rule produces errors when compile, help me to find a solution, 
thanks in advance.

Errors showing in Console given:

```
"[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=simple.drl, line=5, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'CustomerRecord']]"
```